# why "git diff" command returned with "tkdiff error"

Tags: git

I am trying to get the diff of my change in my git local repository.

when typing:

```
git diff
```

I get pop up window with the title: `TkDiff: Error`

and in the box:

```
Error: you specified 7 file(s) and 0 revision(s)
```

I could not find any reference for this.

my version was: `git version 1.7.1`

even when installing later version of: `git version 2.6.4`

did not help here.

Comment: Maybe you can find some info in the config: can you check with `git config diff.tool`?

Comment: how did you install tkdiff on your pc?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are having more files provided for `tkdiff` comparison, which is the difftool specified in the gitconfig.

It seems this feature will soon be supported. [tkdiff discussion forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/tkdiff/discussion/219791/thread/8d9bc12b/?limit=25#d63b)

You can try to use some other diff tool, which supports directory comparison like [examdiff pro](https://www.prestosoft.com/edp_versioncontrol.asp)

Comment: I am not trying to use external diff tool.
I just want to get the diff to be written to the stdout.

Answer (score 0):

OK.

Got it!!!.

I just had to remove the lines

```
[diff]
        external = tkdiff
```

From the global .gitconfig file